# Device Inaccessible Blue Screen after BIOS reset to default profile

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios

Last night I decided to turn my PC off at the wall plug switch after hearing the fans power down, which was a big mistake as when I powered it up today it failed to boot properly.

It restarted several times without entering Windows and then some CMOS BIOS thing popped up something about resetting to default profile. I remember seeing "1. Default Profile" and a countdown of like 10 seconds then another restart and finally device inaccessible blue screen-of-death.

The disk can load its recovery partition and doesn't seem to have any problems according to chkdsk as its only about a month old SSD.

I tried doing some basic BCDedit commands but it doesn't want to play ball and Windows 10 can't repair it automatically. I'm pretty sure the disk is fine and something in the BIOS is causing it not to boot maybe (UEFI configuration or something) but I need some help.

Comment: Can you see the windows automatic repair window? or any windows troubleshooting screen

Comment: yeah it goes to device inaccessible_boot_device :( screen then it restarts and goes into the recovery partition

Comment: If you can access files from the disk, then you can with this utility [BlueScreenView](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/bsod-viewer/9f8bde35-4879-4315-b622-771c35cb44f6) find where is problem.

Comment: after a failed automatic repair..

Comment: also bcdedit /scanos lists 0 installations im thinking this is bios related maybe the data on the installation partition is unreadable given bios settings?

Comment: I meant with other PC (or Windows on other disk) you can get BSOD log files. Also if all fans are connected to the motherboard (or anything Windows can control), then fans aren't the best indicator of powered off PC, Windows can still be running and saving something to disk.

Comment: I just changed GSATA3 control mode to AHCI and PCH Control Mode to AHCI and i am now able to boot into windows the bios had reset it to IDE thanks for the help

Comment: Replace the CMOS battery (likely CR2032) with a new one

Comment: Thanks for the info @JW0914